# Many queries on wordpress and slow server response

Tags: mysql, wordpress, pagespeed

I have wordpress 3.8.6 installed on the Scaleway server (4 X86 64bit Cores,
4GB memory,200Mbit/s Unmetered)
Apache/2.4.18 + PHP 5.6.36 + MySQL Percona Server 5.6.40-84.0

Main page has 4355 queries and it is the cause of slow server response (17.9s)

The function that makes these requests looks like this:

```
        <?php 
        $categories = array(24,121,123,124,127,19,20,91,92,21,22,23,89,29,30,31,38,55,52,65,87,99,120,108,113,119,128,206,159,137,142,139,143,146,147,150,164,153,154,174,175,177,184,186,191,196,198,200,201,204);
        $cats = get_terms('catalog');
        foreach ($cats as $cat) {
            if (in_array($cat->term_id, $categories)) {

                $image = get_field('photo', 'catalog_'.$cat->term_id);

                $query = new WP_Query( 
                     array ( 'tax_query' => array(
                            array(
                                'taxonomy' => 'catalog',
                                'field'    => 'id',
                                'terms'    => $cat->term_id
                            )
                        )) 
                );
                $minprice=0;
                if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
                    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
                        $query->the_post();
                        $fields = get_fields( get_the_ID() );
                        if ((int)$fields['price'] < $minprice && (int)$fields['price']>0 || $minprice==0) {
                            $minprice = (int)$fields['price'];
                        }

                    }
                }
                ?>
                    <a class="cat-item" href="<?=get_term_link($cat);?>" title="">
                    <img src="<?=$image['sizes']['main-category']?>" width="178" height="158" alt="<?=$cat->name?>">
                    <div class="cat-title" style="bottom: 26px;"><?=$cat->name?></div><div style="text-align:center; margin-top: 10px;">Цена от <?=$minprice?> руб.</div></a>
                <?php
            }


        }

    ?>
```

Question!
How can I reduce the response of a server without changing the output functionality?
Can there be recommendations for setting up a MySQL server so that it can process so many requests quickly?
Or how to optimize the code for this function?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin named as [`query-monitor`](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/). You can monitor queries via this plugin.

To reduce query you can use wordpress  [`Transients_API`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API)

Or you can use any cashing plugin like [`W3 Total Cache`](https://wordpress.org/plugins/w3-total-cache/)

Comment: I found the problem in which page.
A large number of queries creates this function - the calculation and output of the minimum price of goods in the catalog: $minprice=0; ... etc.
caching is installed

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bYxZEHGV_eE 
watch this video.  It may help